# FAILED: validateCustomerCreation java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have created the below code for POM framework selenium where I am validating the new customer creation ,but it is giving error

FAILED: validateCustomerCreation
java.lang.NullPointerException

My program is terminating on the first testcase,I have created object of all the pages and intialized the page elements also.

i dont undertand where I am doing the mistake

-created the home pageclass

-created the loginpageclass
-created the customerpage class

-created the test base class to intialize and launch the browser

created the testclass for customercreation

```
public TestLogin() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    super();

}

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
```

//intializing the loginpage,homepage and customerpage

```
    intialization();
    loginpage=new LoginPage();

    homepage=loginpage.login();
    customerpage=homepage.clickOnCustomerLink();

}
```

@Test

```
public void validateCustomerCreation(){

    System.out.println(customerpage.customerPageValidate());

    customerpage.createNewCustomer();

    String title=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Customer Registered Successfully!!!')]")).getText();

    System.out.println(title);


}
```

---

```
 public String customerPageValidate() {

     String title=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(),'Add New Customer')]")).getText();
     return title;

     }

 public void createNewCustomer() {


     customername.sendKeys("Ravi");
     radiobutton.click();
     dateofbirth.sendKeys("20011987");
     address.sendKeys("723 woodwaybluff circle");

     City.sendKeys("cary");
     state.sendKeys("north carolina");

     pin.sendKeys("27513");
     mobilenumber.sendKeys("9192033967");

     email.sendKeys("jipriyaji@gmail.com");

     custpassword.sendKeys("ravi@123");
     submit.click();



 }
```

FAILED: validateCustomerCreation
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can you give more details on the error? It's impossible to know the problem without knowing the stack trace

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.